# Excluding URLS that contain a string in Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using regex to add a survey to pages and I want to include it on all pages except payment and signin pages. I can't use look arounds for the regex so I am attempting to use  the following but it isn't working.

`^/.*[^(credit|signin)].*`
Which should capture all urls except those containing credit or signin

Comment: Explain what you mean by "isn't working", and why you think this regex has anything to do with URLs.

Comment: @ScottHunter I continue to see urls with the words credit and signin in them using a tool checker. Regex is the input allowable for determining placement with optimizely.

Comment: @chrislipsit, Please tag your question with the language the regex is being used in.

Comment: Try with `^(?:(?!credit|signin).)*$`

Comment: @zzzzBov sorry, Javascript

Answer (score 1):

`[` indicates the start of a *character class* and the `[^` negation is per-character.  Thus your regular expression is "anything followed by any character not in this class followed by anything," which is very likely to match anything.

Since you are using specific strings, I don't think a regular expression is appropriate here.  It would be a lot simpler to check that `credit` and `signin` don't exist in the string, such as with JavaScript:

```
-1 === string.indexOf("credit") && -1 === string.indexOf("signin")
```

Or you could check that a regular expression does *not* match

```
false === /credit|signin/.test(string)
```

Answer (score 0):

Whitelisting words in regex is generally pretty easy, and usually follows a form of:

```
^.*(?:option1|option2).*$
```

The pattern breaks down to:

- `^` - start of string
- `.*` - 0 or more non-newline characters*
- `(?:` - open non-capturing group

  - `option1|option2` - `|` separated list of options to whitelist
- `)` - close non-capturing group
- `.*` - 0 or more non-newline characters
- `$` - end of string

Blacklisting words in a regex is a bit more complicated to understand, but can be done with a pattern along the lines of:

```
^(?:(?!option1|option2).)*$
```

The pattern breaks down to:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:` - open non-capturing group

  - `(?!` - open negative lookahead (the next characters in the string *must not* match the value contained in the negative lookahead)

    - `option1|option2` - `|` separated list of options to blacklist
  - `)` - close negative lookahead
  - `.` - a single non-newline character*
- `)` - close non-capturing group
- `*` - repeat the group 0 or more times
- `$` - end of string

Basically this pattern checks that the values in the blacklist do not occur at any point in the string.

<sub>* exact characters vary depending on the language, so use caution</sub>

---

The final version:

```
/^(?:(?!credit|signin).)*$/
```

Comment: Regex101.com says no matches with  the following reference strings 

'/stuff/credit
/rars
/credit
/my-account/arist/signin
/blah/bjah/signin'

Comment: @chrislipsit, but my friend bob said this would work! No seriously, write some code and check for yourself. `['/stuff/credit','/rars','/credit','/my-account/arist/signin','/blah/bjah/signin'].map(function (val){
   return /^(?:(?!credit|signin).)*$/.test(val)
});`